# In search of multiple expressions for a sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, integer-sequences, combinatorial-identities

The sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k^24^k$ is listed [on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A084771) along with a couple of combinatorial interpretations. What interested me at the moment is the plethora of binomial single-sums for the same sequence $a_n$. Here are a few that I have found so far.

(1) Refer to [this paper by D. Callan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4784.pdf) and the paper by V. Strehl, Discrete Math. 136 (1994), 309-346, involving finite sums:
\begin{align}a_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{2k}k2^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\binom{2n-k}n3^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}k4^k5^{n-2k}
=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\binom{2k}k9^k4^{-n}. \end{align}
(2) Let me add my own finite (alternating) sum variants:
\begin{align} a_n&=3\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{2k}k2^k9^{n-k}=
3\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{2n-k}n3^k4^{n-k} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\binom{2n-2k}n\left(\frac94\right)^k\left(\frac52\right)^{n-2k}.
\end{align}
(3) I also have these infinite series versions:
\begin{align} a_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}k\binom{2k}k\left(\frac92\right)^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k}k^24^{-k}\left(\frac94\right)^{n+1} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+2k}{2k}\binom{2k}k\left(\frac4{25}\right)^k\left(\frac95\right)^{n+1}.
\end{align}

> **Question.** Do you know of other definite sums resulting in the same $a_n$?

Comment: Mathematica says the generating function is$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-10t+9 t^2}},$$presumably one can produce lots of stuff from that.